# AgGrid custom header filter not showing

Tags: javascript, angular8, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react

I have the ag grid Enterprise version for Angular, i have implemented the custom header by referring below link.

https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-header-rendering/

i am facing issue when i am trying to implement the filter functionality.
when i click on icon for filter i am getting the error "CustomHeader.html:5 ERROR TypeError: Array.prototype.filter called on null or undefined" and filter popup is not showing up.

aggrid enterprise version no : 20.2.0

Comment: can you add some working demo(reproducing the error) using stackblitz or plunkr that way it will be easy for community to help you on this issue.